# Increase debug item count in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I routinely have to look at `byte [1024]` and longer in the debugger (VS 2008). At least by default, it shows 15 items.  I have 23" widescreens that could display 3 or 4 times that vertically.  Does anyone know how to get more items to display (if it is possible)?

**Clarification**
This is primarily for C# code and I am mostly interested in the inline debugger window (the one that appears with a `+` when you hover over an object in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom [debug visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++ use the `,` format specifier  in the debugger to list the count of elements to display

```
theValue,42
```

The full set of format specifiers for C++ is available here

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, it's mostly C# though.  I gave it a try in the watch window anyways but didn't work ("42 isn't a valid format specifier").  Mostly I am talking about the 'inline object browser' thing ( I don't know what it is called).  I'll add clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a static class for quick and dirty watches:

```
public static class DbgUtil{
 public static string DisplayFrom(Array array,int start,int end){
 /// you get the idea
```

and set a watch or immediate window expression to `DbgUtil.DisplayFrom(0,3,foo)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Mole](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx) can help you

Comment: Looks promising, thanks.  I'm surprised I haven't seen that before.